# Instagram - show the total amount of posts from the user

Tags: wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I am displaying an Instagram feed using the Wordpress plugin "Instagram slider widget". Is it possible to show the total post count? how many post this account has posted? using this plugin or using the Instagram API.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total number of posts for a user with the Instagram API using the GET /users/user-id endpoint.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

The response will include counts of media posted by the user. See https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users